# How can I change specific keybindings in Tmux?

Tags: fedora, configuration, tmux

My hands get tired everytime clicking on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> to activate tmux (prefix) and then <kbd>q</kbd> to switch between panes (pane numbers).

I want to map them to <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd> respectively.

I understand I need to change something in the configuration file `~/.tmux.conf` but I'm not sure what, especially how to refer to Function Keys while mapping, and go beyond prefix's definition, that's refer to `prefix+q` in this case.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't clear as <kbd>q</kbd> by default prints the numbers of the panes, it doesn't switch between them...

Nevertheless, you can achieve what you are after with some simple binds: first, resetting the prefix key to <kbd>q</kbd> and then setting <kbd>F1</kbd> to move to the left pane and <kbd>F2</kbd> to the right. With that knowledge, you can adapt to whatever it is you are actually asking.

```
# set prefix key to ctrl+q
set -g prefix C-q
bind -n F1 select-pane -L
bind -n F2 select-pane -R
```

Note: I have included the `-n` switch which obviates the need for using prefix first, as you indicate you are tired of this. If you *do* want to hit the prefix before changing panes, just remove it.

Comment: Thanks, but what I actually want is to switch to <C-q> mode by clicking F2. I don't know it's "command" name (like `select-pane`) to bind to.

Comment: I use <C-q> <s>as a preliminary step</s> to switch between panes :)

Comment: You mean `list-panes`?

Comment: I just checked `list-panes`, no it's not what I want. I want the command that prints 0,1,2,3 on the screen. The command of Ctrl+Q. BTW thanks for `-n` it's really easy and useful switch :)

Comment: It was `display-panes`. I found it on `man`. I'm accepting the answer.